# Wining Eleven 3, Final Ver No artificial intelligence but how?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I'm Interested in game developing. I read somewhere that there is no artificial intelligence in Wining Eleven 3, Final Ver. I'd love to know how CPU responds to actions and plays. e.g. CPU vs CPU game: what are results based on? and how can a result be different every time?

Any help appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some form of artificial intelligence, or machine learning, in the game, unless it's all random moves.  There's the chance that the "correct" moves have been precalculated for certain inputs, but that seems somewhat unlikely for this game.

Broadly speaking the game probably takes a set of current variable states and runs it through some sort of algorithm to determine the next "correct" moves.  The subtle differences in variable inputs may create the differences (why the game is different every time) or there may be a random number generator in there picking from percent chances for which moves are acceptable.

Comment: Really Thanks, but I've seen my friends that predicting which team wins. is there any explanations for that ?

Comment: There are a few explanations.  The cpu-vs-cpu games may not be as random as they seem, maybe your friends see certain moves or certain styles of play that tell which side is going to win.  An alternative theory is that maybe your friends are just very lucky.

Comment: Thanks, anyway They tell something that from my view is impossible!!. I mean they predict which team will win before the games starts. and every single time it's correct. so what do you think about this? is there anything about the game we don't know? Thanks